# nextauth v4 credentials provider, adding the raw token to the session

Tags: next-auth, next.js13

I am new to nextauth credentials provider, and I have been following different tutorials on youtube and searching for answers here.

I have a web application using next.js and in it I have a bunch of rest apis to get data from mongodb. I have secured the api by accessing the token. I have used Postman to test the apis, and they work when I pass the raw token to in the Authorization header.

I need to get the raw token into the session object for the session call back in next-auth, so I then can call the apis from client side pages.

Any help would be appreciated.

In [...nextauth].js:

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    // Google Provider
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: "Credentials",

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log("In Authorization");
        connectMongo().catch((error) => {
          error: "Connection Failed...!";
        });

        // check user existance
        const user = await Users.findOne({ email: credentials.email });
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error("No user found with this email");
        }

        // compare()
        const checkPassword = await compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );

        // incorrect password
        if (!checkPassword || user.email !== credentials.email) {
          throw new Error("Email or Password don't match");
        }

        // check if user is enabled
        if (user.active === AccountStatus.DISABLED) {
          throw new Error(
            "Account has been disabled. Please contact support to re-enable your account"
          );
        }

        // Value returned will go into token property
        //console.log("Returnng User Object", user);
        return user;
      }
    })
  ],

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      if (user) token.user = user;
      if (account) token.accessToken = account.access_token;

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user, account }) {
      
      
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      const { password, ...tokenPwdRemoved } = token.user;
      session.user = tokenPwdRemoved;
      return session;
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Session callback](https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/callbacks#session-callback):

```
callbacks: {
  async session({ session, token, user }) {
    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken
    return session
  }
}
```

Keep in mind security concerns relating to the token and session.

> **Session callback**
>
> The session callback is called whenever a session is checked. **By
> default, only a subset of the token is returned for increased
> security.** If you want to make something available you added to the
> token through the jwt() callback, you have to explicitly forward it
> here to make it available to the client.